# Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "web": "SECRET_KEY

Tags: django, docker

I'm doing a project online book store on django, when i try to setup environment variable I am facing the problem.

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=secret_key
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    hostname: db
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

and my `settings.py`:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

The secret_key is:

```
SECRET_KEY=-)hy!+7txe6))yhcy4o3ruxj(gy(vwx)6^h&+-i*=0f$4q(&bh
```

Comment: Can you put the secret key in quotes? You could put the secret key in an .env file

Comment: No i did not put the secret key in quotes.

Comment: From your edit, the value of SECRET_KEY is not the string you posted in your yml file. The value in the yml file is `secret_key`. Can you verify the yml file is exactly what you are running with docker-compose, character for character, rather than a rough approximation? Can you also verify that all spaces are spaces, and not tabs or some other whitespace character?

Comment: Where are you setting that `SECRET_KEY` value at the end of your question. Is that what is actually in the docker-compose.yml, or from some other place?

Comment: My problem is solved , My secret key contains $ and i am adding $$ in the beginning of the key that's why it's showing error.Thanks everybody for your response.

Comment: @Prantachakraborty I am facing the same error. Can you please elaborate the solution?

Comment: @ShivangiBhardwaj put "$$' sign in your secret_key For example your secret_key is "something$something", after putting extra '$' sign the secret key will be look like "something$$something". Just put an extra "$" sign.