# docker_compose.yml not outputting the $HOSTNAME when connected to cronjob

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron, dockerfile, cron-task

I am trying to set a hostname variable in the docker-compose.yml file. The below works but not when it is on a cronjob. I suspect this is because cronjobs are set in a different $PATH. This:

```
hostname=${HOSTNAME}.1
```

Will return this when it is run on a cronjob:

```
hostname=.1
```

Although, when I try to use something like:

```
hostname=$(cat /etc/hostname).1
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "0-0": "hostname=$(cat /etc/hostname).1"
```

What is a correct output that I can put in docker-compose.yml that will also work for cronjobs?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62500347/invalid-interpolation-format-for-environment-option-in-service-web-secret

Comment: @cimere Your link doesn't work as then the hostname will print as a literal "${HOSTNAME}.1"